# How to apply Customized Tabs of angular components?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-html, dart-webui

I am trying to apply material **customized tabs** of **angular components** in an AngularDart project, but the tabs which results are only basic tabs the
 CSS doesn't apply to customized tabs of the example components.
How to apply the CSS?

The following code generates the result shown in the image, not the customized tabs as of example.

[image]

app_component.html

```
    <material-tab-panel centerStrip class="tab-panel" [activeTabIndex]="1">
    <material-tab label="tab1">
        Eager Content of Tab 1
    </material-tab>
    <material-tab label="tab2">
        <!-- named-content component simply prints its name when instantiated -->
        <named-content name="Eager Tab (Tab 2)">
            Eager Tab 2 content.
        </named-content>
    </material-tab>
    <material-tab label="tab3">
        <div *deferredContent>
            <!-- named-content component simply prints its name when instantiated -->
            <named-content name="Deferred Tab (Tab 3)">
                Lazy Tab 3 Content
            </named-content>
        </div>
    </material-tab>
</material-tab-panel>
<h1>My First AngularDart App</h1>

<todo-list></todo-list>
```

app_component.scss

```
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/material';
@import 'package:angular_components/material_tab/mixins';

@include tab-panel-accent-color('.tab-panel', $mat-red);
@include tab-panel-tab-strip-width('material-tab-panel[centerStrip]', 400px);
```

app_component.dart

```
   import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';

import 'src/todo_list/todo_list_component.dart';

// AngularDart info: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular
// Components info: https://webdev.dartlang.org/components

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: const [
    materialDirectives,
    DeferredContentDirective,
    MaterialTabComponent,
    MaterialTabPanelComponent,
    NamedContentComponent,
    TodoListComponent],
  providers: const [materialProviders],
)
class AppComponent {
  // Nothing here yet. All logic is in TodoListComponent.
}

/// Simple pass-thru content container which announces its construction and
/// displays a label (in a <p> tag) above the content.
/// Only use this component in demos.
///
/// __Attributes__
/// `name: string` -- Name of component.
@Component(
  selector: 'named-content',
  template: r'''
        <p>{{label}}</p>
        <ng-content></ng-content>''',
)
class NamedContentComponent {
  String get label => '$_componentName Content';
  final String _componentName;
  NamedContentComponent(@Attribute('name') this._componentName) {
    print('Named Component "$_componentName" instantiated');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the result here. Which is what I would expect. The accent color (text, and underline) is red, and the width of the tab strip is 400px. What are you trying to do?

[image: styled tabs]

Comment: The same example I am trying to implement

Comment: Sorry I'm going to need a lot more information. The code you provided is doing exactly what I would expect. Which is the image above.

Comment: I have updated the question with code and result image.

Comment: Are you using the sass_builder transformer in your project? Have you verified the contents of the generated .css file?